# Records not showing up in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We start an operation by making sure a customer has enough items with which to work. So we begin by collecting all their current items in an array:

```
@items = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order")
```

Then we determine how many items they should have. If someone has a free account, they should have 5 items. If it is a paid account they should have 20 items:

```
if current_user.paid
  should_have = 19 # one less than 20 because of 0 position in the array
else
  should_have = 4
end
```

Then, in case we need to add blank records, we figure out where we should start:

```
if @items.empty?
  start = 0
else
  start = @items.length + 1
end
```

If the start is less than or equal to what someone should have, then we add blank records:

```
if start <= should_have
  value = [start .. should_have].each do |v|
      SOrder.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :order => v, :item_id => 0 )
  end

  @items = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order") # reload array
end
```

The records that should be added are not showing up in the database.
Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may come from calling `.length` from an Arel object and not a record set.

```
@items = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order").all
```

However, since you only need a count for the first query, I'd suggest using `.count`.  If I was writing this I'd do something like:

```
number_of_items = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count
number_of_blank_items_to_add = current_user.allowed_items - number_of_items
if number_of_blank_items_to_add > 0
    number_of_blank_items_to_add.times do |num|
        SOrder.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :order => (number_of_items + num), :item_id => 0 )
    end  
end
@str_order = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order")
```

In User model:

```
def allowed_items
   if paid 
       20
   else
       5
   end
end
```

## Better Yet

In User model:

```
has_many :s_orders, :order => "s_orders.order asc"

def add_extra_blank_orders
    number_of_items = s_orders.count
    number_of_blank_items_to_add = allowed_items - number_of_items
    if number_of_blank_items_to_add > 0
        number_of_blank_items_to_add.times do |num|
            s_orders.create(:order => (number_of_items + num), :item_id => 0 )
    end  
end

def allowed_items
   if paid 
       20
   else
       5
   end
end
```

In controller:

```
current_user.add_extra_blank_orders
@str_order = current_user.s_orders
```

While I am sure that you have a good reason, I am questioning why blank items need to be in the database at all.  And, if a after_create hook could be used here.

Comment: thanks. i usually get things working in the controller and then move pieces to the model later. Don't know why... guess its just a bad habit. :=]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
value = (start .. should_have).each do |v|
```

instead of

```
value = [start .. should_have].each do |v|
```

`[start .. should_have]` will just return an array with a single range element in it. `(start .. should_have)` will return a range, upon which the `each` enumerator will work as you expect.

Comment: @Jay, this is a good place to use [ruby-debug](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug). It will quickly pay back the time spent on learning it. You can step through your code and test that the variable values are as expected as you go.

Comment: If you want to quickly debug try just throwing the variables you're wanting to check onto your template. `<%= start %>` etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're using `value` and not sure why you're using it.

Can you use this?:

```
if start <= should_have
  (start .. should_have).each do |order|
    SOrder.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :order => order, :item_id => 0 )
  end
end
@str_order = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order") # reload
```

Edit: I moved @str_order outside of your if statement to make sure you'd always be reloading the array, if this is undesired just switch it back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to ensure your code is entering the loop of creating records by adding `puts "entered the loop"` inside the loop like this:

```
if start <= should_have
  (start .. should_have).each do |v|
    puts "entered loop"
    SOrder.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :order => v, :item_id => 0 )
  end

  @items = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order") # reload array
end
```

If "entered loop" is getting printed, try `.create!` to make sure all the validations are passed(If any of them are failed ActiveRecord error will be raised stating the validation)

```
if start <= should_have
(start .. should_have).each do |order|
  SOrder.create!(:user_id => current_user.id, :order => order, :item_id => 0 )
end

@str_order = SOrder.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("order") # reload array
end
```

Comment: Agree with @rubyprince here, `.create!` might shed some light on any failures you're having.